# excel converts invalid hours into valid hours automatically

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel form which accepts time in 24 hours as hh24:mm:ss.
I gotta check if the entered time is valid or not.

My problem is when I enter valid times like 12:23:23, it catches the value as it is. But when I enter invalid times like 25:34:12, it converts it into valid time as 01:34:12. So I am not able to validate the data.

Why is it so? And how can I stop this from happening?

I am taking the value in variable as:

```
timeVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(ActiveSheet.Range("F" & i), "hh:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use text-to-columns, based on : as a delimiter.  Then you can use an IF statement to determine if each section (or just the first) is invalid (greater than 23).

```
=IF(B2>23,"Invalid","Valid")
```

You can also use a formula on this.

I would also recommend change the formatting of the time field on your form, to protect the integrity of future data.  To do that, go to format > custom > hh:mm:ss AM/PM.

[image]